# SAS Streaming output to Excel

Tags: sas

I'm running SAS stored process to create reports and output in Excel, but the website returns HTML output instead of Excel output.

```
%let rc = %sysfunc(appsrv_header(Content-type, application/vnd.ms-excel));
%let _odsdest=tagsets.ExcelXP;

%stpbegin;

  ods tagsets.excelxp    STYLE=printer    options(sheet_name='XXXXXXXXXX' );
  ODS PROCLABEL='XXXXXXXXXXX';

  PROC REPORT DATA= XXX 
  ---
  ---
  ---

  RUN;
  ods tagsets.excelxp close;

%stpend;
```

I also tried code from [SAS support](http://support.sas.com/kb/40/683.html), still it returns HTML output. What's wrong with my code, or sth does not work in the systems? Thanks

Comment: Hm, i copied your excact code and only replaced the XXX with a table, it returned the report in a excel, so not sure what is going wrong with your system, what versions are you using? Is there more code in the process except the one you showed? If you have also an HTML-Output in same process, excel-output is not working, you can have only one output-type in a process

Comment: appsrv_header should not be the problem, i use it all the time instead of stpsrv_header, but you should also add the Content-disposition line, so the browser knows how to handle the excel

Answer (score 0):

The function is stpsrv_header not appsrv_header